# How to add each Fibonacci value from 1 to n to a list in python?

Tags: python, fibonacci

I have the following code:

```
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.memo = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if not args in self.memo:
            self.memo[args] = self.f(*args)
        return self.memo[args]

@Memoize

def fib(n):

    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

I am trying to improve my basic programming skills, I have the following problem that I cannot figure out how to do, I want to be able to put all the values of fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) in a list so I can filter the list of values based on other criteria.
What is the best way to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

How about just a simple list comprehension?

```
fiblist = [fib(n) for n in xrange(1,n+1)]
```

Comment: do I need to add xrange n+1 to get all the values or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: Funny, I just realized that also. Yes, you want xrange(1,n+1) to get all the values from 1 to n including n.